# Multiple Braintree "Hosted Fields" forms on one page

Tags: javascript, braintree

In my app, I have multiple forms(in my case 2). I need to use braintree hosted fields in each form. All my fields have selector like `[data-braintree-card-number]`. Since I use partial for this form, they have same selectors for hosted fields. I've tried to use selector like `#form_id [data-braintree-card-number]`, but it's not valid css selector. In v2 version of braintree, there was `id` option for form, not sure if it would solve my issue. Everything works fine with one form on page.

How can I setup multiple forms with braintree hosted fields on one page?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Using Braintree's javascript SDK in multiple forms on the same page is possible, but it takes a little setup work.

Braintree does not support using multiple different instances of the `braintree` object at once. In other words, using multiple concurrent instances of `braintree` on a page may lead to unpredictable behavior. To use Braintree with multiple forms on the same page, you should use the [teardown](http://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/3.6.3/#teardown) functionality in the javascript SDK, which removes an existing `braintree` object from a page. Once the previous integration is gone, you can initialize Braintree again without issue.

The Braintree SDK can only see one form at a time, so you'll need a way of choosing what form to instantiate it with. If the form that your customer wants to pay with changes, you'll have to tear down your previous Braintree initialization and re-initialize it with the new form. By initializing and tearing down the `braintree` integration for each form, you can use Braintree with multiple forms on the same page.

Comment: We have a single page app and need to load three instances of the Hosted Fields. Is there a solution that allows all instances of Hosted Fields to load on the same page or do we still need to approach it from the teardown and create approach for each instance when in view? It seems inefficient.